# Website on AWS HTTPS link when clicked it changes to HTTP, using Application Load balancer for https

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, aws-application-load-balancer

I have my web app deployed on EC2 instance, using Load balancer I have applied AWS SSL certificate for HTTPS communication with Web application.

I am using load balancers for two domain name redirections for both HTTP and HTTPS. I have achieved it through rules and conditions.

From load balancers HTTPS rule point to HTTP target on EC2 instance as SSL certificate is present on load balancers not on VM.

It also works fine, unless when I provide HTTPS web app link in some app like WhatsApp, when user clicks on the link it opens in browser the browser but HTTPS changes to HTTP. I think its a HTTP to HTTPS redirection issue, how should I fix this.

Below are the rules screenshot on AWS application load balancers.
[image: HTTPS Rules on LB]
HTTPS Rules on LB

[image: HTTP Rules on LB]
HTTP Rules on LB